# Why is my redirect to the Terms Of Service page no longer working?

Tags: google-analytics-api

I have a program that automatically creates an Analytics account using the Provisioning API. The program creates the accountTicket, grabs the accountTicketId, then redirects the user to the Terms of Service page, as per the Analytics Provisioning API guidelines, using this url "https://www.google.com/analytics/web/#management/TermsOfService//?api.accountTicketId="

When it was working, it would redirect me to the TOS, I would scroll down and hit accept, and then the program would continue on its merry way.

Now, it is redirecting me to this url: "https://www.google.com/analytics/web/?et=&authuser=#provision/SignUp/".

Programs Workflow:

1) Log into the clients email address.

2) Get the OAuth code for this email.

3) Using the OAuth code, generate a temp OAuth token.

4) Create the Analytics account by POSTing to https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/provisioning/createAccountTicket using the OAuth token and the necessary postdata.

5) Get the AccountTicketId from the response and then redirect the user to the TOS page.

Does anyone know why this would be happening?

- I am using .NET for my program.
- I am not using the Client Library.
- AccountTicket creation is working.
- I Verified that the program is grabbing the
  AccountTicketID from the response.
- Mis-redirect only happens to email accounts
  that have zero Analytics accounts. (which is what the program is
  designed for and hasn't been a problem until now). My tester email
  accounts, which have several Analytics accounts already, work as
  expected.
- I verified that my redirect URI in the AccountTicket matches my google project redirect URI.

[Provisioning DevGuide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/provisioning/v3/devguide)

[createAccountTicket](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/provisioning/v3/reference/provisioning)

[Google Groups Link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-analytics-management-api/MHRy0hygHv0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been fixed by a recent [release](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/provisioning/v3/changelog) in which a new URL parameter, "provisioningSignup=false" was added.